# Term for distance between arms or loops of a spiral?

Tags: geometry, terminology

In astronomy, the space between arms of a galaxy is apparently known as the ["inter-arm space"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83760/what-is-the-space-between-galactic-arms-called).

Is there a mathematical term for the shortest distance between two adjacent arms or loops of a spiral? For example, in a simple [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral#Characteristics.), this distance is always $2\pi$ times the multiplier $b$.

I could call this the "inter-arm distance", but perhaps "arm" is not a common mathematical term for the curved lines that make up a spiral.